# Sparse Matrix Resulting in Rank Deficient Correlation Matrix

Tags: correlation, sparse

Suppose I have a matrix with 34 binary predictors and a large number of observations such that there are always 5 ones per observation (i.e., 5 of the predictors are randomly set to 1 in each observations). Most of the matrix consists of 0s:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(132)
R <- 34
m <- 5
reps <- 37980
out <- replicate(reps, {
  row <- rep(0, R)
  idx <- sample(seq_len(R), m)
  row[idx] <- 1
  row
})

X <- t(matrix(out, nrow = R, ncol = reps))
datX <- as.data.frame(X)
V <- cor(datX)
```

My design matrix X is rank 34:

```
rankMatrix(X, method = 'qr')

[1] 34
attr(,"method")
[1] "qrLINPACK"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 8.852918e-12
```

However, my sample correlation matrix $V$ is rank-deficient:

```
rankMatrix(V)

[1] 33
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 7.549517e-15
```

Usually this happens when the design matrix is rank-deficient or nearly so. I must be missing something obvious that's the result of the sparseness of the matrix, but can anyone explain why this is happening?